# What are some good modern interpretations of the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, book-recommendation

What are some good books with a modern outlook at the Mahabharata? The older books carry the weight of conservatism. I'm looking for a writer with an inkling for modern views to interpret the Mahabharata.

Comment: You can try [Yuganta: The End of an Epoch](https://www.amazon.in/Yuganta-End-Epoch-Irawati-Karve/dp/8125014241) by Irawati Karve. You can read the review [here](http://creative.sulekha.com/yuganta-by-irawati-karve-a-book-review_219079_blog). It's not a retelling though, it's a character analysis.

Comment: you mean a fictional retelling without reverence to truth ? if so, this has nothing to do with Hinduism, or it is too opinionated (by definition)

Answer (score 1):

You can read Mahabharata by Kamala Subramaniam [1](https://archive.org/details/mahabharata-kamala-subramaniam/mode/2up). Mahabharata has been retold in a superb manner. Though the book is an abridged version of the great epic, all the important aspects have been covered in it. The style of the book is lucid, the dialogues crisp and the characters come alive in front of the readers because of the descriptions by the author. The story is more than just an epic, it tells the story of heroic men and women, code of life, philosophy of social and ethical relations. You can read Paperbacks if you are willing to understand philosophical themes and other important conversations in detail from here. [2](http://www.ghvisweswara.com/mahabharata-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Sunil P Elayidams new book in Malayalam interprets and decode the Modern time of Mahabharata.

The Epic Mahabharata. Goodwill Books International, New Delhi. You can find the whole interpretation of Mahabharata.

Comment: Welcome to HSE. You can please put both in the same answer. Or better is to write a comment. Just btw the user asking the question has deleted his account